# why cout output memory address not string?

Tags: c++, winapi

i am  tring to use c++ to get display device info ,but cout give me some memory address ,how can i get string value ? output like :00CFF4B4:00CFF5F8,
i am using visual studio 2019

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    DISPLAY_DEVICE d;
    d.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);
    int device_num = 0;

    while (EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, device_num, &d, 0))
    {
        std::cout << d.DeviceName << ":" << d.DeviceID<<std::endl;
        device_num++;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Are you using the `W` or `A` version of `EnumDisplayDevices`?

Comment: @Dai you are right,this is the root cause,thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using the `W` version of `DISPLAY_DEVICE` ([`DISPLAY_DEVICEW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-display_devicew)) which I believe is the default since at least Visual Studio 2015 and later ([the compiler defines `UNICODE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/working-with-strings)).

The `DeviceName` and `DeviceID` members of `DISPLAY_DEVICEW` are `WCHAR` (a macro for `wchar_t`), so you need to use `wcout` instead of `cout`:

```
std::wcout << d.DeviceName << ":" << d.DeviceID << std::endl;
```

Comment: this ansower is correct ,but i am not understand why it works like so ,why not visual studio pop up an error to tell me but just give me an memory address ?